# The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services.vote: 'db'

Tags: yaml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  vote:
    image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before
    ports:
     - "5000:80"
    redis:
     image: redis:alpine
     ports:
       - "6379:6379"

    worker:
     image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker

    db:
      image: postgres:9.4
      environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"

    result:
      image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before
      ports:
          - "5001:80"
```

ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.vote: 'db'

what is error Any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: To me, this looks like an indentation issue. `db` should not be nested that deep

Answer (score 0):

I think `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` should be indented so they're "within' `db`.